# Eclipse won't show Ceylon source files

Tags: eclipse, ceylon

I have created a Ceylon project in Eclipse Oxygen.
There are Ceylon source code files in the folder `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt\milling\source\designs`, but these are not shown inside Eclipse, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

EDIT:

Making a single run, to 'kickstart' Eclipse, seems not possible. In run configuration I cannot click 'Run', for some reason.

Refreshing the Project Structure Window (right click -> refresh) revealed two files in the root:

- `ceylonb`
- `ceylonb.bat`

  but no files in the `source` directory was revealed.

  The problem might boil down to Eclipse not recognizing this as a proper Ceylon project, as suggested by Vitaly Banchenko.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the project was not created as a proper Ceylon project.

When creating the project, choose

`File -> New -> Ceylon project`

rather than

`File -> New -> Project`

Comment: It seems right that you should create a Ceylon project to do Ceylon development. But it certainly should show you all files in your project even I you have create a *General* project! If it didn't there must have been another problem also...